# Retrieve Id of latest record for each user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am asking as the examples I can find don't quite match what my need is.

I have a table:

```
Id        PersonId PersonNumber        StartDate
--------- -------- ------------------- -----------------
1         1        E1                  2020-10-21
2         1        Q1                  2019-01-01
3         2        E2                  2020-10-01
4         2        Q2                  2019-10-01
```

I need to retrieve the Id of the most recent record.  In this case it would be Ids 1 and 3.

I have been using

```
SELECT MAX(Id) AS Id
FROM PersonNumber AS PersonNumber_1
GROUP BY PersonId
```

But that is incorrect because the data may not necessarily have been input in sequential order, so the `MAX(Id)` may actually be an older record. I tried doing `SELECT ID, MAX(StartDate)` but that does not work as `Id` is not used in an aggregation or GROUP BY

How would I get the `Id` of the most recent record for each `PersonId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like `ROW_NUMBER` to "partition" your data by `PersonId`, in order to get the "most recent entry" for each `PersonId` - something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Id, PersonId, PersonNumber, StateDate,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY StartDate DESC)
    FROM
        PersonNumber
)
SELECT 
    Id, PersonId, PersonNumber, StateDate,
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Marc, that gives me the list of Id's I would expect, so thank you for that.  I guess I left out one part of the scenario, I am trying to use those Id's as part of the WHERE clause in a query.  When I add the code in (using only the Id field) it gives an issue with ````WITH````

Comment: ````select * from personnumber where id in (.... insert above code here ...)````

*** I removed all but the Id field from the code you posted above

Comment: @KeithClark: you'd have to write your statement to something like `WITH CTE (....) SELECT * FROM PersonNumber WHERE Id IN (SELECT * FROM CTE)` or use a proper `INNER JOIN` instead  of the `IN` operator